# How i can send image in email with cakephp 3 email template?

Tags: php, html, email, cakephp, html-email

I'm trying to send image into email,
My image code is: `<?php echo $this->Html->image('image-name.jpg', ['class'=>'img-responsive']); ?>`

While i'm debug email template in my localhost, it's working fine, image displaying properly, but when this same code make it live on server and fire email, email content display properly but image not showing(not found).

Any body will suggest proper way to implement it.

Thanks,
Mak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the email or in whole website if you want to full path of content use `fullBase` param with `true` value,

`echo $this->Html->image("logo.png", ['fullBase' => true]);`

Will output:

`<img src="http://example.com/img/logo.jpg" alt="" />`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images

This is a proper way that suggested by CakePhp framework.

Answer (score 1):

First attach the file what you want to send

```
$email->attachments([
    'photo.png' => [
        'file' => '/full/some_hash.png',
        'mimetype' => 'image/png',
        'contentId' => 'unique-id'
    ]
]);
```

And then in your email template, add the unique id

```
 <img src="cid:unique-id">
```

Detail explanation, [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments)

Comment: Thank you for replaying, But i don't want to send attachment, i want to set logo image, that not working for me.

Comment: Heads up: *Deprecated since version 3.4.0: Use setAttachments() instead of attachments().*